# how show response data in other page angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using the code snippet below I'm authenticating email, password. The `customerlogin()` method returns some JSON data which I want to show in the next page. In other words I want to pass the data returned from `customerlogin()` to `then()` and then pass it to `/customerprofile`
Please help

```
login(form) {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (form.$valid) {
      this.Auth.customerlogin({
          email: this.operator.email,
          password: this.operator.password
        })
        .then(() => {

          // Logged in, redirect to home
          this.$location.path('/customerprofile');
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.errors.login = err.message;
        });
    }
  }
```

//Other file Auth.js

```
customerlogin({
      email,
      password
    }, callback) {
      console.log('Customer Authentice Method');
      return $http.post(properties.customer_login, {
        email, password
      })
        .then(res => {
         properties.GetId = res.data.id;
          $cookies.put('token', res.data.token);
          currentUser = User.get();
          return currentUser.$promise;
        })
        .then(user => {
          safeCb(callback)(null, user);
          return user;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          Auth.logout();
          safeCb(callback)(err.data);
          return $q.reject(err.data);
        });
    }
```

i want show data these textbox
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI3SJ.jpg)

Comment: 'and then pass it to /customerprofile'. You want to pass some data to **another** controller?

Comment: yes..i want show my json data in html page using angularjs

Answer (score 4):

Your login function should be calling a service method which makes the ajax call and stores the response as an object property on that service. The controller then has that on scope because you've injected the service. There's nothing to pass. It's already there and is watched automatically by Angular.

Something like this:

```
angular.someModule('someModule')

.service('someService', function($http) {
    return {
        loginCall: function(...) {
            // do ajax call here
            return loginStuff; // must be an object (or wrapped in one)
        }
    };
})

.controller('SomeController', ['someService', function(someService) {
    var sc = this; // controllerAs syntax

    sc.login = function(form) {
        someService.customerlogin(...).then(...).catch(...);

        // because someService has been injected, someService.loginCall is now 
        // available and being watched by the controller, on its scope...
        // and can be used in your view like {{someService.loginCall.dataProperty}}
        ...
    };
}]);
```

There are probably some missing pieces here (module injections), but this should get you started.

Comment: {"_id":"5825978738c03e3c187cd006","full_name":"Addi Khan","email":"adeelkhan@gmail.com"} i want this in then,

Comment: can you please sample code, my English not very good, hard to understand

Answer (score 1):

At first, try to use this construction for your `.then`:

```
  .then(function (data) {
      $log.debug(data); //to console log passed data via angular
  });
```